# Mi código para borrar datos de una tabla a través de Java no me funciona

Tags: java, jdbc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué tiene de malo el String query que he puesto? Por más que trato de usarlo me dice que tengo un error en la sintaxis.

```
public static void borrarDatos(String ID){
        try{
            //String query = "DELETE FROM `personaje` WHERE `ID_Personaje` = "+ ID;
            String query = "DELETE FROM `"+ CrearBaseYTabla.nametabla +"´ WHERE `ID_Perosnaje´ = " + ID;
            System.out.println(query);
            java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(query);
            EliminarDatos.Mensaje.setText("Borrado con exito");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            EliminarDatos.Mensaje.setText("Error al borrar los datos "+e); 
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error dice com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxisErrorException: Unknown column ´ID_Personaje´ in ´where clause´

Comment: Bienvenida a SO, debes de poner tu codigo en texto con formato de codigo para poder analizarlo y trabajar con el facilmente.

Comment: Has probado a quitar las comillas simples del nombre de la tabla y del nombre de la columna?

Comment: Por favor lee el artículo sobre [cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), recuerda que las imágenes son para ayudar un poco a entender mejor la pregunta, pero no se debe de abusar de ellas. Por favor edita tu pregunta y coloca el código mínimo necesario para que tu problema sea reproducible

Comment: Y he tratado quitando las comillas y me va peor TnT

Yo único que me genera problemas es esta parte

Comment: Muestra el mensaje exacto de error que estás teniendo. Y un consejo: utiliza `prepared Statements`, ya que tu código actualmente es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxisErrorException: Unknown column ´ID_Personaje´ in ´where clause´     Ese es el error que me arroja

Comment: ¿No será Personaje en lugar de Perosnaje?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error son las comillas que tienes en esta linea:

"DELETE FROM `"+ CrearBaseYTabla.nametabla +"´ WHERE` ID_Perosnaje´ = " + ID;

La que esta despues del FROM `(esta comilla es la del error)

La que esta antes del where: ´ WHERE

Tambien a `ID_Perosnaje´  omite esas comillas.

Debe de quedar asi:
String query = "DELETE FROM "+ CrearBaseYTabla.nametabla +" WHERE ID_Perosnaje = " + ID;

Te recomiendo que utilices el debuger de netbeans detenlo en tu caso en la línea 150, es decir después de donde tienes declarada la variable String query.
Después tomas el valor que lleva la variable query esto con el objetivo de ver si formaste bien el delete, copia todo ese valor y pégalo en tu gestor de base de datos ejecútalo y ahi te veras si esta bien o no.

Espero y te sirva mi explicación.